# The difference between sum of reciprocals of prime and reciprocal of subset of composite numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $c_j$ represent all composite numbers that are divisible by primes but not by their subsequent powers, for example, 6,15 but not 8 (divisible by $2^3$). Then what is the value of
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_i}-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{c_j}$$

Comment: $(1)$ Do you mean the first $n$ squarefree composite numbers ? $(2)$ The second sum must run over $j$ $(3)$ I doubt that there is a nice closed form expression, but asymptotics can probably be found.

Comment: sorry was the mistakes here n tends to infinity

Comment: As $n$ tends to infinity, the entire expression obviously tends to negative infinity.

Comment: Yeah i realised my  mistake does this question make sense

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{n_i}$$ where $n_i$ is a natural number greater than one which is divisible by $k$ prime numbers but does not have any prime repeating in its prime factorization